# Not able to fetch value form input box when checkbox against it is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have few input boxes that come dynamically from the database and after that, I have input boxes that can be increased when a user clicks on a link

```
<?php
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM child where adult_id = '$user_id'   ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
        $name = $row["name"];
        $age = $row["age"];  
        $price = $row["price"];      
?>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age">
       
<?php }} ?>

<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="child">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="add-field"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> <span>Add another learner</span></span>
</div>

<script>
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
   
});
<script>
```

However what I am not able to do is that when a user checks a checkbox then name, age, and price against that checkbox gets displayed inside another .

**POINT HERE TO NOTE** is that for every row the price remains the same but name and age will vary and in the end I need to display the total of all the prices.

The code that I was able to do was to fetch the value when the checkbox is clicked, but it fetches only 1 value, after that, I am stuck and not able to move forward

Apart from the code above the checkbox code [is here](https://codepen.io/samya/pen/YzwVYzB)

Would appreciate if someone could help me

> I am also attaching images if that can help in a better understanding of the situation

[image: final result]

[image: second scenario]

Comment: So, basically the behavior is that when you select a student from above, the student should appear in the bill list and sum to the total?

Comment: yes, however the initial few input will be created acc to a database value as you can see i have place first input inside while loop and based on the condition there can be more than one input field inside the loop, outside the loop the input field increase on the click of link and here user can add as many as they want

Comment: I have to go out for a bit, but I'll try to check it later today.

Comment: and depending on the input fields(db generated+user generated), a new row of price is introduced, along with the details given in the input fields and at the end there will be the total of the price

Comment: Yeah sure. no issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your checkbox is clicked you can use `each` loop to see which all checkboxes are checked or unchecked depending on that you can create your html with required datas .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });

});
var data = ""
//when checkbox is clicked
$(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
  var total = 0;
  //empty previous data
  $("#result").html("");
  var lengths=$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  console.log(lengths)
  //if length is > 0 then only looped
  if(lengths > 0 ){
  var data = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
  //looping through all checkbox
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    //checking if checkbox is checked
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //get name and age
      var name = $(this).closest(".form-row").find("input[name=name]").val();
      var age = $(this).closest(".form-row").find("input[name=age]").val();
      //add the same
      data += "<tr><td>" + name + " </td><td> " + age + "</td><td>180$</td>  </tr>";
      total = total + 180;

    }
  });
  //add total as well
  data += "<tr><td colspan ='3'> TOTAL :" + total + "$</td><tr></table>";
  //append data
  $("#result").append(data)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="child">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="add-field"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> <span>Add another learner</span></span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```