# when checkbox is checked not able to fetch data that are against that checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have data that is displayed in the form of a table and each row has a checkbox.
I am trying to fetch the data of each row when the checkbox is clicked against that row.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_age"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_age"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ></td>
</tr>
```

These  will get generated dynamically, so the naming needs to same for the input box, however when i am fetching the value typed by the user,it fetches the value of only first row, and the values is getting repeated multiple times

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var arr = [];
            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
                
                var one = $("[name='child_name']").val();
                var two = $("[name='child_age']").val();
                
                arr.push(one)
                arr.push(two)
                return arr;

                
                
            }).get();

            console.log(data);
            $('#post-result').append(data);
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone please tell how to resolve the issue

Comment: Hey @Sam I modified the structure a little bit, but I think it would work better for you. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute in this case could complicate things a little bit. What I would do is use data-attributes to have specific identifiers for each row. Something like this:

**UPDATED**

I changed the behavior to work with dynamically added rows.

Using `$(document).on("click"...` you can affect future elements of the same type while `$("[type='checkbox']").click()` works only for currently existing elements.

I also took some liberty in expanding the example.

```js
var children = [];

$(document).on("click", ".child-selector", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      
      var info = [];
      info.push($(".child-name[data-id='"+ id +"']").val());
      info.push($(".child-age[data-id='"+ id +"']").val());
      
      console.log(info);
      
      // An example of using objects to give some structure to the data
      // and then store it to an array with all the checked rows
      var child = {};
      child.id = id;
      child.name = $(".child-name[data-id='"+ id +"']").val();
      child.age = $(".child-age[data-id='"+ id +"']").val();
      
      children.push(child);
      
      console.log(children);
   } else {
      console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
      
      // An example of removing the specific children from the array
      children.forEach(function(child, index) {
        if(child.id == id) {
          children.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      console.log(children);
   }
});

var clickCounter = 0;
var dataCounter = 13;

$("#add-child").click(function() {
   var html = '<tr>'+
              '<td><input type="text" class="child-name" data-id="'+ dataCounter +'" value="Child '+ clickCounter +'"></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" class="child-age" data-id="'+ dataCounter +'" value="'+ clickCounter +'"></td>'+
              '<td><input class="child-selector" type="checkbox" data-id="'+ dataCounter +'"></td>'+
              '</tr>';
   $("table").append(html);
   clickCounter++;
   dataCounter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-name" data-id="9" value="John Connor"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-age" data-id="9" value="12"></td>
      <td><input class="child-selector" type="checkbox" data-id="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-name" data-id="10" value="Jane Connor"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-age" data-id="10" value="12"></td>
      <td><input class="child-selector" type="checkbox" data-id="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-name" data-id="11" value="Tom Connor"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-age" data-id="11" value="13"></td>
      <td><input class="child-selector" type="checkbox" data-id="11"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-name" data-id="12" value="T800"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="child-age" data-id="12" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="child-selector" type="checkbox" data-id="12"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="add-child">Add Child</button>
```

Now, if you need to send the data via post you should review your usage of name because as it currently is it would only send one value.

Comment: yes i may send the data via post, but these <tr></tr> and value inside them is getting generated dynamically, i.e on a click of a link a new <tr> gets introduced along with <input> tag inside them, still trying to figure out that part

Comment: Do you have control over that part?

Comment: @Sam I added an example of how to handle dynamically added inputs.

Comment: Also, another question is the array supposed to contain only one child or do you want to select all the children that are checked?

Comment: Yes I have access to backend, and yeah i wish to fetch all the values of that particular row against which the checkbox is, this ques is part of another ques, " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539398/not-able-to-fetch-value-form-input-box-when-checkbox-against-it-is-checked " would be great if you could check this link

Comment: @Sam, check the update I did, I made it so that you could add all children to an array when checked and remove specifically unchecked rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `context` parameter of [`$(selector [, context])`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to only search inside the current `<tr>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var arr = [];

      var one = $("[name='child_name']", $tr).val();
      var two = $("[name='child_age']", $tr).val();

      arr.push(one)
      arr.push(two);

      console.log(arr);
      $('#post-result').append(arr);
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      console.log("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_name" value="A Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_age" value="A Age"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_name" value="B Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="child_age" value="B Age"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<pre id="post-result"></pre>
```

Comment: It is giving 18 pairs of value in the result

Comment: @Sam oh, ok, I think your `map` should be removed. Updating my answer

Comment: @Sam I updated it, I'm not sure if it's what you meant

Comment: thank you, initially it was giving undefined value but now it seems to be working

Comment: you might want to loo into this another post, this ques is subpart of that post: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539398/not-able-to-fetch-value-form-input-box-when-checkbox-against-it-is-checked